# How to add a custom view from a xib to a UIScrollView?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, xib, nib

**Problem**

I am trying to add a custom view from a xib into a UIScrollView.

I added a UIScrollView to an empty ViewController in my storyboard. I also added 4 constraints for leading, trailing, top, bottom to Safe Area and set them all Equal to 0.

Now in the code I want to add a custom view "EquipmentInfoView" to the existed UIScrollView

```swift
class EquipmentInfoVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        equipmentInfoView = EquipmentInfoView.instantiate()
        scrollView.addSubview(equipmentInfoView)
    }
}
```

And it does not work as the ScrollView does not scroll. How should I do it instead?

Here is the custom view "EquipmentInfoView"

```swift
class EquipmentInfoView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var nameTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var equipmentImageView: UIImageView!

    static func instantiate() -> EquipmentInfoView {
        let view: EquipmentInfoView = initFromNib()
        return view
    }
}
```

**Extra Notes**

I know this is not the normal way to create a custom view from xib. However, this way I dont have to set the File's Owner to "EquipmentInfoView", instead I set the View's Custom Class to "EquipmentInfoView".
(Setting File's Owner to "EquipmentInfoView" gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I do unit testing)

For clarity, this is how I would add this view to a normal (non-scroll) view:

```swift
equipmentInfoView = EquipmentInfoView.instantiate()
mainView.addSubview(equipmentInfoView)
equipmentInfoView.frame = mainView.bounds
equipmentInfoView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the contentSize of your scrollView

```
class EquipmentInfoVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        equipmentInfoView = EquipmentInfoView.instantiate()
        scrollView.contentSize = equipmentInfoView.frame.size
        scrollView.addSubview(equipmentInfoView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not solve the problem